# Designing a User/Account model with owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have a simple setup of `Account` and `User` :

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

accounts
--------
id
name
...
```

.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

users
-----
id
account_id
username
...
```

Now, how do I design that an `Account` has an "owner" (a user that has full privileges over the account). The options I can think of:

1. Add a boolean field on User called `account_owner`? (Does not feel right to me)
2. Add a field on `accounts` table called `user_id`, thus creating a kind of chicken-and-egg problem.
3. Something else? Roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work? You'd need to add an `owner_id` foreign key to `Account`.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

# Somewhere in your code...

account = Account.create(name: "Account 1")
owner   = User.create(username: "tom")

account.users << owner
account.users << User.create(username: "sarah")
account.owner = owner
account.save
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought of this - it is the option #2 above (albeit not showing the belongs_to call)

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why there's a chicken-and-egg problem though. Can you explain?

Comment: Just the fact that if I was to do it the "right" way, i.e. every account *must* have an owner and every user *must* belong to an account, then the respective `user_id` and `account_id` cannot be NULL in the database level constraint, and so neither can be created since one is required by the other. But it will simplify things if I go with this approach and not require non-NULL for `user_id`.. I might be over-thinking this. Analysis paralysis!

Comment: Okay, I understand now. My approach would be to handle that at the application level rather than the database level. I would ensure that any time an Account is created the initial "owner" User is generated and assigned at the same time.

Comment: Yes, that is the approach I was thinking of and will follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible that an account can have multiple owners you could add a role column to user.

```
@user.account == @account && @user.role == 'admin'
```